# Delphi TTaskDialog show/hide or start/stop marquee progress bar

Tags: delphi, ttaskdialog

I have a `TTaskDialog` that has an `OnButtonClicked` event handler, in which a lengthy process (several seconds) is performed.  This works fine, but I'd like some indication to the user that things are happening while that lengthy process is chugging along.  I would like to have a marquee progress bar on the dialog that is initially hidden, appears when the `CommandLink` is clicked, and runs while the lengthy process is performed - I'd settle for a progress bar that is visible but not enabled when the dialog is displayed and is "turned on" in the `OnButtonClicked` event.  Just including the `tfShowMarqueeProgressBar` flag causes the bar to appear and be scrolling when the dialog first displays, and the `ProgressBar` property of the dialog doesn't have `Enabled` or `Visible` type properties to control this behavior.

There are TaskDialogs in Windows itself that do what I want, so I know it's theoretically possible, though I realize that the structure of the VCL wrapper around the native control may make it difficult or impossible using the VCL object.

Is what I want possible using the `TTaskDialog` VCL object?

Comment: You can presumably use the raw Win32 API. That's how I've always done it.

Comment: I use the [SynTaskDialog wrapper unit](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/03/05/Open-Source-SynTaskDialog-unit-for-XP,Vista,Seven) from @Arnaud Bouchez

Answer (score 2):

The Windows API provides the message [TDM_NAVIGATE_PAGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tdm-navigate-page) to change the TaskDialog at runtime. You would have to pass a [TASKDIALOGCONFIG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/ns-commctrl-taskdialogconfig) structure along with this message that defines the dialog's properties. In its `dwFlags` field you could specify the `TDF_SHOW_PROGRESS_BAR` flag to show the progress bar. But this requires a lot of work as the other fields in the `TASKDIALOGCONFIG` structure must match the properties that you have set for Delphi's `TTaskDialog` component.

Delphi creates a `TASKDIALOGCONFIG` structure as a local variable in the function `TCustomTaskDialog.DoExecute` in `Dialogs.pas` that is used to display the TaskDialog.

Comment: There's no point trying to use the built in wrapper. Just go straight to the underlying api.

Comment: Thanks, all.  I ended up deferring the lengthy processing to a daily cleanup process which is done in a background thread.